# Saving data into a model from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller, which saves fine for that specific controller and model (accesspoint). However, i want to save a particular data into another model (radhuntgroup) - which i do not know how.

```
   def create
    @accesspoint = Accesspoint.new(params[:accesspoint])
    @accesspoint.user_id = current_user.id
    o = [('a'..'z'), ('1'..'9'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
    @accesspoint.secret = (0...30).map{ o[rand(o.length)] }.join

    respond_to do |format|
      if @accesspoint.save
        format.html { redirect_to accesspoints_path, notice: 'Access Point has been added.' }
        format.json { render json: @accesspoint, status: :created, location: @accesspoint }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @accesspoint.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

the above looks fine for accesspoint controller and model (saves all the parameters from form into the accesspoint table) however, i want to save one particular data into another field into the radhuntgroup table.

accesspoint view.

```
%= simple_form_for @accesspoint, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">  
    <div class="controls">
    <%= f.input :shortname, :label => false, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Access Point Name', :hint => 'example: quadifi_hotspot' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                accesspoints_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div> 

<% end %>
```

in this case, i hope to duplicate the "shortname" column in the accesspoint table into the radhuntgroup table in the "groupname" column. - which i am looking at using the controller to do this.

If i were to do it in PHP for example, this would be a lot easier but i am dealing with legacy databases which most parts of backend is already "hardcoded" this way and i cannot fully follow the conventions.

Comment: try this in controller after creating accesspoint:- Radhuntgroup.create(:groupname => params[:accesspoint][:shortname])

Comment: If you do so, then they wont be done in a transaction. Right way would be to move this logic to model. In `after_create` hook of `Accesspoint`.
BTW, what's the relationship between `Accesspoint` and `Radhuntgroup`? If they are associated models, `accepts_nested_attributes_for :radhuntgroup` along with `f.simple_fields_for :radhuntgroup` can be used.

Comment: accesspoint's relationship is has_one to radhuntgroup. I will try accepts_nest_attributes_for (which is used to create nested forms)

if i were to do f.simple_fields_for which is ok and i can write hidden fields for it. however, this information will be exposed to the outside world and not really secure.

@user2788206 - i will try to do that as well i have tried somewhat similar but with stringify errors.

Comment: @user2788206 - your solution worked fine. :)  My mistake was doing Radhuntgroup.create(params[:accesspoint][:shortname]) - just in case someone ran into the same problem.

- vss123 - i also would love to know of moving this into the model. after_create sounds a very neat solution as well. :)

Comment: What is the equivalent for destroy action if i destroy the record in accesspoints model?

Comment: If you have accesspoint_id column in raghuntgroup then use dependent: :destroy option on `Accesspoint` model

Comment: @nishanthan - this would mean i would need to modify the Radhuntgroup.create method as well.

    Radhuntgroup.create(:groupname => params[:accesspoint][:shortname], :accesspoint_id => params[:accesspoint][:id]) - which would result in "nil" in accesspoint_id field.

Comment: To save the `accesspoint_id` it is better to save via nested_attributes. So in create action simply build `@accesspoint.build_radhuntgroup(:groupname => params[:accesspoint][:shortname])` and just save @accesspoint. Its enough upto destroy associated Radhuntgroup while destroying Accesspoint records.

Comment: Thank you. I never had thought using nested_attributes would work. I would usually use it to build nested forms and just doing in controllers only is something new to me.